# how to list all files in a directory which contain only one dot

Tags: unix, ls

I am trying to get all files in a directory which contain only one extension dot such as abcd.py and not abcd.efg.py

i've tried `ls ~/scripts/[^.].py` with no success

Comment: Is your shell `bash`? If so, can you use the `extglob` shell option?

Comment: eventually, I used the find command. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

eventually, I used: find ~/scripts/ -regex "[^.]*.py"